# Getting ActivityNotFoundException on specific device to open Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

In my app I open Google Maps with following code.

```
String map_url = "geo:0,0?q=";
map_url += String.valueOf((double)latitude / 1E6) + ",";
map_url += String.valueOf((double)longitude / 1E6);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
intent.setData(Uri.parse(map_url));
startActivity(intent);
```

And it has been working fine with many devices. But today I saw ACRA's crush report.

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
```

The device is Vortex running OS2.2.2. Exception clearly tells me I need to declare "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity" in manifest. The question is, I did not do this but it works for many devices, so result is not consistent: Why I get exception on that device and I did not get for many other devices?

Please not saying "You need to add that to manifest." In that case, please tell me why some (not all) devices work without exception.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your map_url string has inadvertently resolved an ongoing issue I've been having with trying to get the built-in maps app to service requests when started as an intent. "geo:0,0?q=" was the key, THANKS!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`com.google.android.maps` is a different application/package so declaring it in your AndroidManifest won't give you what you want. I believe the Android installation does not have the Maps application installed and hence can not receive the fired Intent.

Comment: like Abhinav said, declaring it in your AndroidManifest wont do anything. You only have to declare your own activities in the AndroidManifest. I suggest surrounding it with a try/catch, and displaying a message telling the user that he/she needs to download google maps from the market and giving the user a link that takes him/her there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and thank you @magicman clearing advice me what I should do. I will what you advised.